# How am i could get typecheck by extend parametrs from array of functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm trying to create function which take parameters from **funcArray** argument parameters and use like its own. I want to use this argument as plugins with additional parameters.
How am i able to get typechecking when i'm adding function to funcArray  parameter?

```
function func1({a, h} : { a: number, h: number}) {
  return a + h
}

function func2({b} : { b: string}) {
  return `__${b}__`
}

const arrayOfFunctions = [func1, func2]
// get type mergeFirstArg = { a: number } & {b: string }
type mergeFirstArg = Parameters<typeof func1>[0] & Parameters<typeof func2>[0]
// get type dynamicMergeArgs = { a: number } | {b: string }
type dynamicMergeArgs= Parameters<typeof arrayOfFunctions[number]>

type composeParameters = {
  funcArray: ((a: any) => any)[]
}

function compose<T extends composeParameters> ({ funcArray, ...props }: T & Parameters<T["funcArray"][number]>[number]) {
  return funcArray.reduce((acc: T, func: (a: any) => any) => ({ ...acc, ...func(acc) }), { funcArray, ...props })
}

// able to pass everything, no typechecking at all
const result = compose({
  funcArray: [func1, func2],
  a: 1,
  b: '1',
  d: '2'
})
console.log(result)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSBGAFAbwIYF9EBcimi2RYIAtgEYCmATgDSIAWRAzlPTGAOa4BKYgChEierSgh6SbMNzDhKaPCTKATFmr4iJahy49+QzKPGTpSavMUQEnUvXrYAngHlgAMXAr7iALyIANrKqMwaALrCAPTRiLySiFAuAA60iJQMCZ4w9JwAgvS8AcSk5FR09Ij4AGTE+oic3HzVwslpGVm0OXlQhcWBAArYzplQDOwAPO20cMDIPqgAfEEADBGIdcOjkhPTqbPzGivrMXEJUEkHiAAmLmDYlDAQALJd-ewlJGSIFDQM1UQAB96gZmsUFDNbvdHs83kVaB8hiNHrs8vs0nNHM53F4fLB7EE-pUIktFFC7JQUnB2LRtqjxnkvmZlIUcUR0OgftgwC4hP4lqReQIglEFEp8apEJTqbTJgAVRC0AAe4zAN0+MppdJRYwmgvQwCIiq2urRU3lQQARKynK4rREiRUGKSnf96BETGY7GB2HAADa0AB0-rgvENAhsZ1I1EDSTgiBS2HYn1oADcGC4oCwjMwwAmZhAWLQIABrIykS7Yf3+4Ra2lYFk+NmuIghRbhHzqCKMMw-MJmBoAclQQ97YhuRCH6iH8gEQA)

I have tried infer and so far i have found only this solution

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having a hard time understanding this. The code in plaintext differs from the code in your playground link.  The plaintext code logs `{ 0: "_", 1: "_", 2: "1", 3: "_", 4: "_", funcArray: (2) […], a: 1, b: "1", d: "2" }` which is ‍♂️. What type do you expect `compose()` to return?  Could you give some examples along with the actual types you expect to see, instead of just an approach that (apparently) doesn't work?

Comment: Do you just want the first argument of each function intersected together? So you can pass the same object to each function and have each function be satisfied? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJBBkW)?

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2118W) is what you're looking for?  Really hard to tell without a [mre] and a clearer description.